# replace comma in json file's field with jq-win

Tags: json, csv, jq, gsub

I have a problem in working JSON file. I launch curl in AutoIt sciript to download a json file from web and then convert it to csv format by jq-win

```
jq-win32 -r ".[]" -c class.json>class.txt
```

and the json is in the following format:

```
[
{
"id":"1083",
"name":"AAAAA",
"channelNumber":8,
"channelImage":""},
{
"id":"1084",
"name":"bbbbb",
"channelNumber":7,
"channelImage":""},
{
"id":"1088",
"name":"CCCCCC",
"channelNumber":131,
"channelImage":""},
{
"id":"1089",
"name":"DDD,DDD",
"channelNumber":132,
"channelImage":""},
]
```

after jq-win, the file should become:

```
{"id":"1083","name":"AAAAA","channelNumber":8,"channelImage":""}
{"id":"1084","name":"bbbbb","channelNumber":7,"channelImage":""}
{"id":"1088","name":"CCCCCC","channelNumber":131,"channelImage":""}
{"id":"1089","name":"DDD,DDD","channelNumber":132,"channelImage":""}
```

and then the csv file will be further process by the AutoIt script and become:

```
AAAAA,1083
bbbbb,1084
CCCCCC,1088
DDD,DDD,1089
```

The json has around 300 records and among them, 5~6 record has comma in it eg DDD,DDD
so when I tried read in the csv file by _FileReadToArray, the comma in DDD,DDD cause trouble.

My question is: can I replace comma in the field using jq-win ? 
(I tried use fart.exe but it will replace all comma in json file which is not suitable for me.)
Thanks a lot.

Regds
LAM Chi-fung

Answer (score 1):

> can I replace comma in the field using jq-win ?

Yes.  For example, use `gsub`, pretty much as you’d use awk’s `gsub`, e.g.

```
gsub(","; "|")
```

If you want more details, please provide more details as per [mcve].

### Example

With the given JSON input, the jq program:

```
.[]
| .name |= gsub(",";";")
| [.[]]
| map(tostring)
| join(",")
```

yields:

```
1083,AAAAA,8,
1084,bbbbb,7,
1088,CCCCCC,131,
1089,DDD;DDD,132,
```

Comment: I tried few days and still not figure out how to use gsub with jq-win... what more detail you want ? Thanks.